# Reflection get field of singleton static nested class

Tags: java, reflection

I've got the following class:

```
public class A {
    private static class B {
        private static final B instance = new B();
        private ArrayMap<String, Integer> map;
    }
}
```

I'm trying using reflection to obtain the map field, but I don't understand
what to do. My current code is:

```
    Class<?>[] classes = ainstance.getClass().getDeclaredClasses();
    for (Class c : classes) {
        if (c.getName().equals("com.foo.A$B")) {
            try {
                Field f = c.getDeclaredField("instance");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Field f1 = c.getDeclaredField("map");
                f1.setAccessible(true);
                ArrayMap<String, Integer> map;
                try {
                    map = (ArrayMap<String, Integer>) f1.get(f.getType());
                    System.out.println(map.get("id"));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is not working? You should be around long enough to understand how to write "code not working" questions.

Comment: `f1.get(f.getType())` -> `f1.get(f.get(null))`, perhaps? Without a stacktrace, it's hard to know what's going wrong.

Comment: `f.getType()` doesn't make much sense. It should be `f.getValue(null)`.'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP It's not my code, so I can't do anything

Comment: `map = (ArrayMap<String, Integer>) f1.get(f.getType());` seems fishy...but its hard to tell what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: @greywolf82 There is nothing in the *code* about 'static inner'. These are your words, in your question and your title.

Comment: @EJP It's an internal class with static, I don't know how you can call it.

Comment: It is a nested static class. If it wasn't static it would be an inner class. See [JLS #8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
            Field f = c.getDeclaredField("instance");
            f.setAccessible(true);
```

one needs to get the `instance` object:

```
            Object instance = f.get(null); // null as static, no 'this'.
```

Then the same for map, now not with null, but `instance`.

```
                map = (ArrayMap<String, Integer>) f1.get(instance);
```

One could drop the generic type parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's worked.